# I'm getting a segmentation fault in GCC compiler

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

The segmentation error occurs in this function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int heap [999],heap2 [999]; 

int* addDigit(int *arr, int SIZE, int D) {
    int con=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        con = con * 10 + arr[i];
    con += D;

    int p = 0;
    while (con >= 0) {
        heap[p] = con % 10;
        con /= 10;
        p++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);

    heap2[0] = 11;
    heap2[1] = -1;

    int *pp = heap2;

    return pp;
}
```

This is main function:

```c
int main() {
    int N, digit; 
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int arr[N];
    for (int index = 0; index < N; index++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[index]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &digit);
    int *ptr = addDigit(arr, N, digit);
    int index = 0;
    while (*(ptr+index) !=-1) {
        printf("%d", ptr[index]);
        index++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting a segmentation fault here?

This program gets input of array like `[1 2 3]` and value `k`, say 3;
it should print `1 2 6`.

I used two globally declared arrays here.

Comment: "I'm Getting segmentation fault in GCC compiler" -- no, you are not. You are getting a segmentation fault in _your program_, not in the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the quickest way to locate the sources of segmentation faults, is the compile the program with the `-g` flag to include debug information in the executable, and then to run the program using [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

In this case, the segmentation fault occurs in the reading of `heap` here:

```c
while (con >= 0)
{
    heap[p] = con % 10;
    con /= 10;
    p++;
}
```

The variable `con` will eventually become `0` and will *stay* at `0` due to the repeated division by 10. It will not become negative, and thus the while-loop will repeat infinitely. The index `p` will increase until the program will try to access element 999 of `heap` - which is out of bounds, i.e. this is a segmentation fault.

Perhaps you meant to write `while (con > 0)`? This stop the loop when `con` is zero (instead of negative, as before). Or perhaps you need a different solution, depending on what the intended functionality of the code is exactly.

PS. The segmentation fault does *not* happen "in the compiler", it occurs while the program is executed.